# Заголовок Qt приложения меняется некорректно

Tags: qt

Хогчу соединить сигнал объекта `textEdit textChanged()` со слотом `documentModified()`. Тело слота:

```
void MainWindow::documentModified()
{
    setWindowTitle("[*]");
}
```

Ожидаю, что при записи текста в `textEdit` будет вызываться этот сигнал, а слот по меняет заголовок на `[*]`. В результате при наборе текста приложение меняет заголовок на имя проекта `TextEditor`.
Для этого в конструктуре MainWindow соединяю сигнал со слотом: 
`connect(ui->textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(documentModified()));`

Подскажите, почему заголовок меняется не так, как я это прописал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что строка `[*]` - это плейсхолдер (шаблон), указывающий, где в заголовке должна появляться звездочка при использовании механизма [windowModified](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModified-prop).
По умолчанию windowModified = false, поэтому звездочка не отображается, а вместо пустой строки отображается название исполняемого файла.

Я бы вам посоветовал использовать механизм windowModified.

В конструкторе установить заголовок окну:

```
setWindowTitle("Название документа[*]");
```

и в слоте устанавливать свойство `windowModified`:

```
void MainWindow::documentModified()
{
    setWindowModified(true);
}
```